# SF movie where the main character hits the "end of the road" when trying to exit from the city

Tags: story-identification, computers

I've tried searching trough top lists for this movie. I only remember little from this movie, I may even be wrong off a general gender.

Anyway, the reason I'm pretty confident it actually belongs to this site, is because of this scene I can't forget. Just like in "The Truman Show" when Jimmy hits the wall of sky, so does the ( main ?) character from this movie: he hits some kind of digital road end, when he tries to exit the city. He drives a car, goes trough all the stop signs on the road, and meets the green lines, just like in unfinished computer 3d model of a world.

Is this single scene enough to identify the movie?

Comment: Dont mind this, I have proven that if you really want something, you should really try harder about it. Movie name: The Thirteenth Floor, 1999. And, I wasn't a kid back than, guess I only have amnesia or something.

Comment: You're allowed to post this as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Strucker: sorry, I noticed your comment after answering. Do you want me to remove my answer?

Answer (score 21):

This seems to be  "[The Thirteenth Floor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0139809/)" (1999), and what you describe is actually on the DVD cover. A very nice film, though probably low budget, based on the novel "[Simulacron-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulacron-3)" written in 1964 by [Daniel Francis Galouye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_F._Galouye). This is to my knowledge the first story in the Matrix family,  probably better because much less ambitious. There is another film, based on the same story, called "[World on a Wire](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070904)" ("Welt am Draht", 1973) directed by [Rainer Werner Fassbinder](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001202/), produced in 2 episodes for TV, and released on DVD a few years ago.

I recommend all, even if not as flashy as current blockbusters.

[image: End of the World]

Comment: What makes you think The 13th Floor is related to the Matrix series? At first glance this seems unlikely - there's no obvious crossover of personnel and the 2 films came out within a couple of months of each other which makes them look much more like competitors than siblings.

Comment: @NigelHarper Sorry if my statement is unclear. I was thinking of the thematic
family. I am not saying there is any direct connection between the two
films. But they have in common the idea of different levels of
reality, some being more real than others. Matrix does not do it with
computer simulation, but that is secondary. The other point is that
the main characters in the story can move between realities, while
most are unaware of the situation. I am not alone in seeing a
similarity between the two works. See for example
[simulacron-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulacron-3) in
Wikipedia.

Comment: Fair enough. That makes more sense, but I think in that case the wording is unclear - I read it as implying a much closer relationship than just thematic similarity.

Comment: @NigelHarper Note also that I was actually referring to the story, i.e., the book
by DF Galouye, that was published 35 years before the film Matrix was
produced. There was most likely some cultural influence, direct or indirect.

Comment: Added the picture I think the OP was asking about. Should confirm it enough for an accept, assuming he's ever back here again :)

Comment: @KHW Nice idea - Thanks - It is a very telling picture, even though it is hard to imagine what a "spatial" end of the world could look like. Another vision is Google satellite pictures, that become less precise as you get distant from urban centers. But it is from above ... and it is much less spectacular. The OP will be back when he has another question about identification :-)

Comment: @NigelHarper - I saw an interview a few years ago with the Wachowski brothers where they cited 13th Floor, Dark city and a few others as being major influences on their filmmaking.